# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : validation on optional field triggers validation errors in ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core 6/7 MVC, we have classes like this. Model is user in view. How to not have validation for credentials field and only have validation for fullname and position (as this is what the user is allowed to edit)? Thanks.

Configuration: project properties are

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>


public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Credentials = new UserCredentials();
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Position")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public UserCredentials? Credentials { get; set; }
}
```

Now, `UserCredentials` class looks like this:

```
public class UserCredentials
{
    public UserCredentials()
    {
        Username = string.Empty;
        Password = string.Empty;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be between {2} and {1} characters long.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Re-enter Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match.")]
    public string ComparePassword { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the `[Required]` decorators found on the UserCredentials class members?

Comment: no i cant. it gets used somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Validating the properties of UserCredentials couldn't be avoided,but in MVC project,you could try to remove them from ModelState:

```
foreach(var prop in typeof(UserCredentials).GetProperties())
            {
                var propname = "Credentials." + prop.Name;
                ModelState.Remove(propname);
            }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks. i have created a separate model and now mapped the model with this one.